# ZIP and Library context menu issues

Tags: windows, menu, registry

I'm developing a context menu-based utility for Windows (7, currently), but I'm having some issues.

As you probably know, to create a context menu for files and/or folders, you must, respectively, create keys in:

1. `HKCR\*\Shell\`
   and
2. `HKCR\Directory\Shell\`

### Problems

1. When right-clicking on `ZIP` files, the folder context menu is appearing, when I would like the file context menu.
2. The file context menu for `URL` files only appears when interacted with from within a Library, as you can see here:

   Non-Library interaction
   [image]

   Library interaction
   [image]
3. Context menu commands for `LNK` files only get executed when interacted with from within a Library

Comment: Creating the verb in `HKCR\AllFileSystemObjects\Shell\` fixes the weird Library behavior, but it's not a fix, as I need different file and folder sub commands. Can anyone work off of that?

Comment: It's been a while since I messed around with shell extensions, but don't you get the list of objects for which to build your menu?  Can't you just examine them and build your menu appropriately?